# How to generate performance stats of clustering from flexclust?

Tags: r, cluster-analysis

After trying a few clustering algorithms, I got the best performance on my dataset using [`flexclust::kcca`](http://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/flexclust/versions/1.3-4/topics/kcca) with `family = kccaFamily("angle")`.

Here's an example using the `Nclus` dataset from `flexclust`.

```
library(fpc)
library(flexclust)
data(Nclus)

k <- 4
family <- flexclust::kccaFamily("angle")
model <- flexclust::kcca(Nclus, k, family)
```

Now I want to optimise the number of clusters.  The most comprehensive set of performance metrics for cluster models seems to be found using [`fpc::cluster.stats`](http://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/fpc/versions/2.1-10/topics/cluster.stats).  This function needs two inputs: a distance matrix, and the clusters that were assigned.

The latter is easy; it is just `model@cluster`.

I'm struggling with what to provide for the distance matrix.  `kcca` doesn't return a distance object (or if it does, I haven't found it).

I guess that typically I would use `dist(Nclus)`.  In this case, I don't want the Euclidean distance (or any of the other methods available to [`dist`](http://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/stats/versions/3.3.1/topics/dist)) – I want the distance measure used by the clustering algorithm.  I can recreate the distance matrix used by `kcca` using the code from that function.

```
control <- as(list(), "flexclustControl")
centers <- flexclust:::initCenters(Nclus, k, family, control)
distmat <- distAngle(Nclus, centers$centers)
```

Then I should just be able to calculate the cluster model stats using

```
fpc::cluster.stats(distmat, model@cluster)
```

The trouble is that is giving me two warnings about the the distance argument.

```
Warning messages:
1: In as.dist.default(d) : non-square matrix
2: In as.matrix.dist(d) :
  number of items to replace is not a multiple of replacement length
```

That makes me suspect I'm giving it the wrong thing.

How should I pass the distance matrix to `cluster.stats`?

Comment: Incidentally, `fpc::cluster.stats` requires a lot of memory, so it is impractical for even moderately sized datasets.  I went with `cluster::silhouette` in the end.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I guess you should use

```
distmat <- distAngle(Nclus, Nclus)
```

However, I am not sure that this makes sense from the modelling viewpoint: to examine the performance of your clustering output you should use the metric which is more suitable to your specific use case; this might (or might not) be the L1 distance:

```
distmat <- dist(Nclus, "manhattan")
```

In particular, I'd guess that minimising the "angle between observation and centroid / standardized mean" is not the same as minimising the intra-cluster angle between the observations; also I'd guess that the latter quantity is not particularly useful for modelling purposes. In other words, I'd regard the distAngle as an alternative way ("trick") to identify the k clusters, but I would then evaluate the identified clusters by other metrics. Hope this makes any sense to you...

Comment: I agree with renato. The problem is that `cluster.stats()` expects a symmetric pairwise distance matrix with every element compared against every other element (e.g. `as.matrix(dist(Nclus))`). The `distAngle(Nclus, centers$centers)` expression however is comparing the datapoints with the cluster centroids, so you get a non-symmetric distance matrix.

As such, you will need to either use a different distance measure, such as the L1 distance suggested by renato, or find a different approach to evaluate the cluster assignments.